# Copy Exact Dynamic Table and Values from one JSP to Another

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I created a dynamic calendar, which consists of check boxes per day, and this will be populated, the calendar is being constructed when a specific year was selected on the drop-down box. I used JavaScript to construct the HTML table and jQuery's append to display it. My problem is that when this calendar was successfully drawn in the JSP, user will input values check boxes, and clicking a button will redirect to a **new** JSP (this will be a confirmation screen in where it will reflect the calendar created in the previous JSP, along with the check boxes input.)

Anyone could give me an idea on how to implement this?

My code for constructing the calendar:

```
// Retrieves the first day of the month (Zero-based.)
              function getFirstDay(year, month) {
                var firstDate = new Date(year, month, 1)
                return firstDate.getDay()
              }

              // Retrieves the number of days of a specific month.
              function getMonthLength(year, month) {
                var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                var thisMonth = new Date(year, month, 1)
                var nextMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 1)
                var length = Math.ceil((nextMonth.getTime() - thisMonth
                        .getTime())
                        / oneDay)
                return length
              }

             // Draws the calendar of a specific month in a specific year.
              function constructTable(month, year) {

                var firstDay = getFirstDay(year, month);
                var totalDays = getMonthLength(year, month);

                var counter = 1;
                var blankCounter = 0;
                var done = false;

                var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
                    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                    "October", "November", "December"];

                var propertyName = 'selected' + months[month];

                var baseline = '<table class="outputTable" summary="Calendar_'
                        + months[month]
                        + '"><tr><th colspan="7">'
                        + months[month]
                        + '</th></tr><tr><th>Sun.</th><th>Mon.</th><th>Tue.</th><th>Wed.</th><th>Thu.</th><th>Fri.</th><th>Sat.</th></tr>';

                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                  if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    baseline += '<tr>';
                  } else {
                    baseline += '<tr class="gray">';
                  }

                  for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {

                    if (i == 0 && blankCounter < firstDay) {
                      blankCounter++;
                      baseline += '<td></td>';
                      continue;
                    }

                    if (counter == totalDays) {
                      done = true;
                    }

                    if (counter <= totalDays) {

                      var index = counter++
                      switch (j) {

                      case 0:
                        baseline += '<td class="daySunday"><input type="checkbox" name="'
                                + index
                                + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                                + index
                                + ' </td>';
                        break;
                      case 1:
                        baseline += '<td class="dayMonday"><input type="checkbox" name="'
                                + index
                                + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                                + index
                                + ' </td>';
                        break;
                      case 2:
                        baseline += '<td class="dayTuesday"><input type="checkbox" name="'
                                + index
                                + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                                + index
                                + ' </td>';
                        break;
                      case 3:
                        baseline += '<td class="dayWednesday"><input type="checkbox" name="'
                                + index
                                + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                                + index
                                + ' </td>';
                        break;
                      case 4:
                        baseline += '<td class="dayThursday"><input type="checkbox" name="'
                                + index
                                + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                                + index
                                + ' </td>';
                        break;
                      case 5:
                        baseline += '<td class="dayFriday"><input type="checkbox" name="'
                                + index
                                + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                                + index
                                + ' </td>';
                        break;
                      case 6:
                        baseline += '<td class="daySaturday"><input type="checkbox" name="'
                                + index
                                + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                                + index
                                + ' </td>';
                        break;

                      }

                    } else {

                      baseline += '<td></td>';

                    }

                  }

                  baseline += '</tr>';

                }

                baseline += '</table>';

                return baseline;
              }
```

Comment: you can use jquery to find all cheked checkboxes and store them in a cookie then next page you can get values from cookie. https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: will it fill the check boxes value after the calendar was generated by JS?

Comment: yes if you write to fill it checkboxes. JS is very helpful to do it for you :) you just need to write to cookie and next page read from the cookie and fill boxes accordingly

Comment: @özkanpakdil thanks I'm going to try it. Thank you!